# Disable blank text fields

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, chat

I am building an iOS app with a chat. Everything works fine except that when user type in a blank message with the space bar it posts an empty message and I would like to disable this.

Is there any way I can check what the user typed in to disable blank inputs?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line will check for whitespace and enter input you can add NSString method `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`

```
[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]

NSString *testString = @" Your string 
";

NSString *trimmedString = [testString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


if (trimmedString.length > 0)
{
  // Code to Post message 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't list any code for when / how your messages get posted from the UITextField, but this sure sounds like something that some method in the [UITextFieldDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a) can take care of for you.

For example: using [`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a), don't allow posting if `textField` has a new length of zero characters.

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple you need to check textfield length and if any textfield length is 0 then disable what you want...

```
NSString * str=@"jit";

NSUInteger  num=[str length];

NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)num);

if([str length]==0)
{
        //Do what you want here
    NSLog(@"String null"); 

}
else
{


}
```

Comment: ... why don't you add some code and explain how to do this? This is more like a half-assed-answer-comment at the moment? Whilst it appears simple for you, the OP wouldn't be asking the question if it was "simple" for him. Your answer also doesn't cover the OPs question, which is about blocking entries which contain spaces.